# MySQL Trigger checking for existing rows with possible NULL values

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have an InnoDB table with a unique index on `performance_id`, `ticket_rank_id` and `ticket_type_id`.

All of these id's have relations to other tables, but their values can also be `NULL`. 
MySQL allows duplicate rows if one of the column values is NULL so I decided to build a `trigger` for this problem.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_performance_tickets` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `performance_tickets` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE num_rows INTEGER;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_rows FROM performance_tickets
WHERE performance_id = NEW.performance_id 
AND ticket_rank_id = NEW.ticket_rank_id
AND ticket_type_id = NEW.ticket_type_id;

IF num_rows > 0 THEN
   // Cancel insert action
ELSE
   // Perform insert action
END IF;

END
```

The problem is `AND ticket_rank_id = NEW.ticket_rank_id` where I have to check if `ticket_rank_id` is NULL or has a value.

`AND ticket_rank_id = NULL` does not work, it only works if i do `AND ticket_rank_id IS NULL`.

Is there any slick solution for this or do I have to write separate queries depending on `NEW.ticket_rank_id` and `NEW.ticket_type_id` being NULL or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_rows FROM performance_tickets
WHERE performance_id = NEW.performance_id 
AND IF(NEW.ticket_rank_id IS NULL, ticket_rank_id IS NULL, ticket_rank_id = NEW.ticket_rank_id)
AND IF(NEW.ticket_type_id IS NULL, ticket_type_id IS NULL, ticket_type_id = NEW.ticket_type_id)
```

Seems to work, now I have to figure out how to abort the insert if `num_rows == 1`. But that's a different problem.

Thanks anyways ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add extra `OR` condition for NULL values `(ticket_rank_id IS NULL OR ticket_rank_id = NEW.ticket_rank_id)` because NULL compared with anything return `FALSE`. Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO num_rows
FROM performance_tickets
WHERE performance_id = NEW.performance_id
      AND (ticket_rank_id IS NULL OR ticket_rank_id = NEW.ticket_rank_id)
      AND (ticket_type_id IS NULL OR ticket_type_id = NEW.ticket_type_id);
```

Comment: Sorry that won't work, it should only check for `IS NULL` if `NEW.ticket_rank_id` is actually `NULL`

Comment: I'm sorry I might have not explained it well enough. I figured it out now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's okay. Welcome to StackOverflow! :)